# Node concurrency / Express request lifecycle / Possible race condition?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I'm building a multi-tenanted Node application, where the tenant is identified via query string.

I also have an API client that makes authenticated (oauth) requests based on the site.

My question is whether I can keep the API client around as a singleton object, and just update the session inside it - and whether I would run into race conditions as a result of another request coming in at the same time while I'm doing asynchronous operations with the client.

```
const session = new Session({ apiKey: 'xxx', secret: 'xxx' })

const client = new Client({ session })

app.use((req, res, next)=> {
  res.locals.client = client;
  next()
})

app.use((req, res, next)=> {
  let { client, db } = res.locals;
  if (req.query.tenant) {
    return db.Tenant.findOne({ tenant: req.query.tenant })
      .then((tenant)=> {
        client.updateSession({ 
          access_token: tenant ? tenant.access_token : null 
        })
        next()
      })
  }
  next();
})

app.get('/test/api', (req, res)=> {
  let { client } = res.locals;
  client.get('products').then((products)=> {
    // What if another request from another tenant comes in right here?
    // Is it possible for the session to be swapped out underneath me?
    return products.get(2).someAsyncFunc().then((product)=> {
      return res.json(product)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: hmm... i do see a possible issue with `client.updateSession`. i don't know what it does, so i can't be sure. Definitely looks like it would be an issue. One solution would be to give each request it's own `client`.

Comment: Yeah updateSession just sets a prop on on the client instance. Sounds like I need a new instance per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is whether I can keep the API client around as a singleton object, and just update the session inside it

No, create a unique instance of the `Client` object for each request. Definitely `client.updateSession` looks like tainting a shared object with non-shared data.

Just change this line

```
res.locals.client = client;
```

to this:

```
res.locals.client = new Client(new Session({apiKey: 'x', secret: 'x'}));
```

And you should be safe now.

Comment: Thanks! My suspicion is I'm prematurely optimizing - but I just worry about the memory / efficiency of creating new clients on every request. For instance, this client has about ~20 sub resources underneath it that are constructed when the client is.